# mysql lock multiple insert for same value, insert after completion of first

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a web application, in which I need to insert records through API for any vendor. Multiple table get updated at the same time like vendor score, vendor performance etc. I would like to handle a scenario in which at the same time i got three-four request from API for the same vendor say v001 then it insert values one by one. Like when got first request then add remaining request in queue for same vendor, after completion first insert second one and so on...

**Example:** 
I am using MySql as database and PHP5.

I have vendor table with 100 vendors i.e V001, V002, V003 .... V100,
Table Name: vendors
Columns: Vendor_id, vendor_name, vendor_address.
another table : score, columns: vendor_id, score

based on some feedback question/answers that I will got in API, I need to calculate the vendor score and inset it into score table. Problem is that when I have multiple requests at very same time then score is calculated incorrectly as It pick up feedback of second request.

I want to make a queue if there is same vendor API requests at the same time and insert into database after completion of first one, Now it is working fine If got multiple different vendors in API.

Lets say server got 5 API request for V002 at same time then first insert first API data and holds for others after completion first move to second and so on.

How to keep track of vendor id so that I can identify it is on process and how to hold the other requests if inserting values for same vendor?

Please suggest suitable solution for this.

Comment: This is what real databases do for you automatically

Comment: @RiggsFolly InnoDB is quite capable of doing this, OP just needs to read up a bit on transactions and locking

Comment: thanks for reply, yes database do automatically but here something extra that need to be handle, like in single api request data is inserted 6 tables and score is calculated based on all 6 table records, as described if it has data for other request score will not be calculated correctly

Comment: @Vatev  in that case how transactions will work. I have one API request for vendor V001 that insert data in  6 tables here I can use transactions but If I have 2-3 another request that separately insert data for own request now in database I have records for vendor V001, from 2-3 request, I just wanted to stop inserting parallel if same vendor is in process

Comment: @Vatev Thats what I think I said